# Is it possible to step through an SSRS Expression?

Tags: sql, ssrs

I have a very complicated IIF statement. Is there a way to step through that expression to see where it goes into either the true or false paths through report builder or another tool?

Comment: so my gut reaction is prolly not. usually an expression format bolted onto the side of a software platform doesn't really compile in the way a debugger would require. Additionally, query based expressions are generally declarative in nature, which doesn't lend itself to iterative analysis. I do recommend that you recognize that at some point, (and I won;t say whether or not you have hit it)  it becomes time to bring the DBAs in to implement views or procedures that assist in your reporting work. a 4NF data schema is a beautiful thing to a DBA or appdev, but is the bane of the report writer.